# Error within HTML Code

Tags: javascript, html

I am in the process of writing a webpage. I have everything done that is needed, however, when you enter any `quantity` over 30 it will make the `id = "shipping"` color red. It does this but it does it for anything less than 30 as well. Also I am having trouble with my submit button sending off to a server/url. Any help is appreciated! I will attach my code!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title> Widgets R' Us </title>

  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Check if non -number or a negative number
    function realNumber() {

      var qty1 = document.getElementById("Quantity1").value;
      var qty2 = document.getElementById("Quantity2").value;
      var qty3 = document.getElementById("Quantity3").value;

      //isNaN is a predetermined function
      if ((isNaN(qty1) || qty1 < 0) || (isNaN(qty2) || qty2 < 0) || (isNaN(qty3) || qty3 < 0)) {

        alert("The quantity given is not a real number or is a negative number!");
        return false; //Will not allow for data to go to server. 
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function total() {

      var p1 = document.getElementById("Price1").value; //Value is referenced to the input tag
      var p2 = document.getElementById("Price2").value;
      var p3 = document.getElementById("Price3").value;
      var qty1 = document.getElementById("Quantity1").value;
      var qty2 = document.getElementById("Quantity2").value;
      var qty3 = document.getElementById("Quantity3").value;
      var over = qty1 + qty2 + qty3;

      if (realNumber()) {
        var totals = (p1 * qty1) + (p2 * qty2) + (p3 * qty3);
        var yes = (totals).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("ProductTotal").innerHTML = "$" + yes;

        if (over > 30) {
          document.getElementById("shipping").style.color = "red";

        } else {
          document.getElementById("shipping").style.color = "black";
        }
      }
    }

    function checkOut() {

      if (total()) {
        if ((document.getElementById("shipping").style.color == "red") &&
          (document.getElementById("extra").checked)) {

          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>

    <h1><b><big> Widgets R' Us </b></strong>
    </h1>

    <h2><b> Order/Checkout </b></h2>

    <form name "widgets" onsubmit="return checkOut();" action="https://www.reddit.com/" method="get">

      <div id="mainTable">

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Widget Model:</td>
            <td>37AX-L
              <td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Price per Unit:</td>
            <td>$12.45 <input type="hidden" id="Price1" name="Price1" value="12.45" /</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>State:</td>
            <td>Regular</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quantity:</td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="Quantity1" name="Quantity1" value="0" /</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <tr>
          <td> &nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Widget Model:</td>
            <td>42XR-J</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Price per Unit:</td>
            <td>$15.34 <input type="hidden" id="Price2" name="Price2" value="15.34" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>State:</td>
            <td>Regular</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quantity:</td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="Quantity2" name="Quantity2" value="0" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <tr>
          <td> &nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Widget Model:</td>
            <td>93ZZ-A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Price per Unit:</td>
            <td>$28.99 <input type="hidden" id="Price3" name="Price3" value="28.99" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>State:</td>
            <td>Regular</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quantity:</td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="Quantity3" name="Quantity3" value="0" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <tr>
          <td> &nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Product Total:</td>
            <td>
              <p id="ProductTotal"> 0 </p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" id="extra" name="extra"> </td>
            <td>
              <p id="shipping">If the quantity exceeds 30 units, there will be extra shipping!</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>

      <tr>
        <td> <input type="Submit" value="Submit" /> </td>
        <td> <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="total()" /> </td>
      </tr>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _“Also I am having trouble with my submit button sending off to a server/URL.”_ — And what is that trouble?

Answer (score 5):

Problem with your values qty1,qty2,qty3. these values are reading as string. so instead of addding these values , its concatinating the strings. replace

```
  var qty1 = document.getElementById("Quantity1").value;
  var qty2 = document.getElementById("Quantity2").value;
  var qty3 = document.getElementById("Quantity3").value;
```

with

```
  var qty1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Quantity1").value);
  var qty2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Quantity2").value);
  var qty3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Quantity3").value);
```

It will Solve your problem with 'Red'.

For the submit button, function `total()` is not returning anything. so change something like

```
  function total() {

   var p1 = document.getElementById("Price1").value; //Value is referenced to the input tag
   var p2 = document.getElementById("Price2").value;
   var p3 = document.getElementById("Price3").value;
   var qty1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Quantity1").value);
   var qty2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Quantity2").value);
   var qty3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Quantity3").value);
   var over = qty1 + qty2 + qty3;

   if (realNumber()) {
    var totals = (p1 * qty1) + (p2 * qty2) + (p3 * qty3);
    var yes = (totals).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("ProductTotal").innerHTML = "$" + yes;
    if (over > 30) {
      document.getElementById("shipping").style.color = "red";
      return true;

    } else if(over>0) {
     document.getElementById("shipping").style.color = "black";
     return true;
    }else{
     document.getElementById("shipping").style.color = "black";
     return false;
    }
 }
 }
```

and  `checkout()` as

```
function checkOut() {
  if (total()) {
    if (((document.getElementById("shipping").style.color == "red") &&
         (document.getElementById("extra").checked))||
        (document.getElementById("shipping").style.color != "red")) {

         return true;
    }
  }
  return false;

}
```

Comment: Please use parse int correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: thank you!! However in checkout() i am trying to get it to send if it is red and checked or if it is not red, but can not seem to figure it out. I am using proper && and || but still having issues, solution?

Comment: Modified the answer accordingly..Please check it now

Comment: If it is working as you expected, please accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
var over = qty1 + qty2 + qty3;
```

With

```
var over = parseInt(qty1) + parseInt(qty2) + parseInt(qty3);
```

Comment: Please use parse int correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1):

There were some minor HTML errors but the real issue is that numeric strings were being concatenated.  So, to get the quantity values you need to use parseInt() to extract the integer value so that math is performed instead of string concatenation. Also, it's a little odd that the user has to click the Calculate Button in order to see a total. The button does work correctly, but is this what you really want?

One more thing, as tempting as it may be to directly alter the color of elements with JavaScript, in terms of keeping the code more robust, it is preferable to simply change the class name as the code does in this example since I created two classes in the CSS for this purpose.

The form now submits as long as the checkbox is unchecked and the units do not exceed 30.  I changed the method to "post" and adjusted the true/false return statements in checkOut(). Note when data is submitted using the POST method, then no form data appears appended to the URL; for more info see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data). I also altered the totals() function so that now it returns a value, namely the total price.

```js
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;

var qty = [0, 0, 0, 0];
var shipping = d.g("shipping");

function realNumber() {
  var qtyInvalid = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (let i = 1, max = qtyInvalid.length; i < max; i++) {
    qtyInvalid[i] = (isNaN(qty[i]) || qty[i] < 0);
  }

  if (qtyInvalid[1] || qtyInvalid[2] || qtyInvalid[3]) {
    console.log("The quantity given is not a real number or is a negative number!");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function total() {
  var over = 0;
  var price = [0, 0, 0, 0];

  for (j = 1, max = price.length; j < max; j++) {
    price[j] = d.g("Price" + j + "").value;
    qty[j] = d.g("Quantity" + j + "").value;
  }

  var totals = 0;
  var yes = 0;
  const radix = 10;

  for (q = 1, max = qty.length; q < max; q++) {
  over += parseInt(qty[q], radix)
}  
  //console.log(over);

  if (!realNumber()) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let k = 1, max2 = price.length; k < max2; k++) {
    totals += (price[k] * qty[k]);
  }

  yes = (totals).toFixed(2);
  d.g("ProductTotal").innerHTML = "$" + yes;

  shipping.className = (over > 30) ? "red" : "black";
return totals;
} // end total

function checkOut() {
  var retval = false;
  var shippingIsRed = (shipping.className == "red");
  var extraChecked =  d.g("extra").checked;

  if ( total() ) {
    retval = (!shippingIsRed &&  !extraChecked)? true :  false;
  }
  return retval;
} //end checkout
```

```css
h1 {
  font: 200% Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

p.red {
  color: #f00;
}

p.black {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <h1>Widgets R' Us</h1>

  <h2>Order/Checkout</h2>

  <form name="widgets" onsubmit="return checkOut()"  action="https://www.example.com/"  method="post">

    <div id="mainTable">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Widget Model:</td>
          <td>37AX-L
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Price per Unit:</td>
          <td>$12.45 <input type="hidden" id="Price1" name="Price1" value="12.45" </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>State:</td>
          <td>Regular</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quantity:</td>
          <td> <input type="text" id="Quantity1" name="Quantity1" value="0" </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <tr>
        <td> &nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Widget Model:</td>
          <td>42XR-J</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Price per Unit:</td>
          <td>$15.34 <input type="hidden" id="Price2" name="Price2" value="15.34"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>State:</td>
          <td>Regular</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quantity:</td>
          <td> <input type="text" id="Quantity2" name="Quantity2" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <tr>
        <td> &nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Widget Model:</td>
          <td>93ZZ-A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Price per Unit:</td>
          <td>$28.99 <input type="hidden" id="Price3" name="Price3" value="28.99"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>State:</td>
          <td>Regular</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quantity:</td>
          <td> <input type="text" id="Quantity3" name="Quantity3" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <tr>
        <td> &nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Total Price:</td>
          <td>
            <p id="ProductTotal"> 0 </p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox" id="extra" name="extra"> </td>
          <td>
            <p id="shipping" class="black">If the quantity exceeds 30 units, there will be extra shipping!</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>

    <tr>
      <td> <input type="Submit" value="Submit" /> </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="total()"> </td>
    </tr>

  </form>
```

I also removed some unnecessary repetitive code that fetches the quantity values, taking advantage of JavaScript closures and for-loops.

Comment: Please use parse int correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @JonP Thanks and duly noted.  Not an excuse, but way back in 1999, I don't recollect that we worried about that second parameter.